# Has anyone benchmarked the use of helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At the moment I am taking code from my views and putting it into
helpers. Great for understanding and maintaining  my views, but using
helpers for the same code must take longer to load.
Has anyone done any benchmark to see whether it takes microseconds or
milliseconds extra to load.

Answer (score 0):

It does add to load.

However, if you really care about performance, then this doesn't *really* matter because caching is where it's all at.

Refer to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Thanks for that response I have not used cache as yet, so it might be something I should look into.